# How to locally download a .tar.gz file on the server created using TarArchiveOutputStream

Tags: java, compression, tar, apache-commons, apache-commons-compress

I am using the owner accepted best answer in [Compress directory to tar.gz with Commons Compress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461393/compress-directory-to-tar-gz-with-commons-compress) for my project.

I am able to create the .tar.gz file on the server, but I am unable to download it locally.

```
    ...
    File f = new File(path);
    System.out.println(f.exists());
    String entryName = base + f.getName();
    TarArchiveEntry tarEntry = new TarArchiveEntry(f, entryName);
    tOut.putArchiveEntry(tarEntry);

    if (f.isFile()) {
        IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(f), tOut);
        tOut.closeArchiveEntry();
    ...
```

Any suggestions on what can be done with `tOut` or after `IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(f), tOut);` to download the .tar.gz file locally. Currently its being generated in path.
Thanks

Comment: It might help if we even knew what `tOut` was. This question is entirely too vague.

Comment: It's probably going to be safer to generate the tar file first, write it to a web response then possibly delete the file if storage is an issue

Comment: @ElliottFrisch tOut is `TarArchiveOutputStream`. Aplogies for the vagueness, basically I want the program to automatically download the created .tar.gz file from the server to my machine locally